# Application Net 1.1 about w3wp.exe memory leak in server

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, .net-1.1

I have application web based net 1.1 Every three or four hour I have the restart my iis server because the performance becomes so slow , nothing will function with message memory leak. I traced the problem to the w3wp.exe in windows server 2003, Using the task manager, I can watch as memory is being added to this exe each time I open or refresh my web pages, but I never see memory released. Eventually there will be so much memory consumed, the web server will slow right down to nothing with display error memory leak and other message.

I don't know about solve that, I needed for monitoring memory used w3wp.exe so I can to release memory normal.

This Message

### Server Error in '/myserver' Application.

> Exception of type System.OutOfMemoryException was thrown. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type System.OutOfMemoryException was thrown.

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type System.OutOfMemoryException was thrown.]

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:1.1.4322.2443; ASP.NET Version:1.1.4322.2470

Comment: Could you please post the actual exception, with the stack trace?  That will help locate the problem.

Comment: This Day i have again.. That Message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it isn't likely to be the `w3wp.exe` process itself, but the assemblies that it loads to run your application. I would check through your source code and make sure that you are releasing unmanaged resources, closing connections and disposing of `IDisposable` types.